# can I propose a new tag: hand-signs for solfège?

Tags: discussion

I wonder what experience  teachers all around the world have made with this method of Kodaly of which I would hold my hand in the fire that it is most successful that I propose to add a new tag: **hand-signs**

https://www.musical-u.com/learn/what-is-kodaly-and-how-does-it-relate-to-ear-training/

Comment: Tags are here to help people find the questions we already have, not for evangelisation.

Comment: nice association, Dan ;) hand-signs could really come from sunday school. http://www.thebubblebox.com.au/blog/do-re-mi-solfege-hand-signs-teach-young-children/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We don't create tags unless we find there is a need for them. Typically this means there are enough questions appearing about that specific topic that aren't already covered by relevant tags.

So far we have had no questions about hand signes, and so few on solfege that these would easily be asked under that tag.

Remember tags are just an extra help to the search engine. It already searches in the body and title of questions and their answers.

Comment: there is certainly no need for something as long something is not known even it might be helpful. 
"tags are just an extra help to the search engine" is plausible.

Comment: "plausible" is not really relevant here. The main reason is the one I stated. This is why new users do not get tag creation privileges. We create tags **after** we have seen there is a need, not speculatively.

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe that such a tag would be super helpful. There already exists a tag 'solfege', which should cover all the questions that would require a specific hand-signs tag.